# Updating Openpyxl from 2.3.2 to 2.4.1 causes error with .rows[rowNumber] is there a workaround?

Tags: python, python-2.7, openpyxl

I've just updated openpyxl as I needed some of the new features but now this has broken all my old scripts. This is the main error I am getting:

```
TypeError: 'generator' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

I have many instances where I would take either a row or column and then store it as a list:

```
templateHeaders = []
    for templateHeader in activeSheet.rows[0]:
        templateHeaders.append(templateHeader.value)
```

Now the `.rows[rowNumber]` or `.columns[columnNumber]` no longer works. I've tried changing this to `.iterrows` but none of this works with the rest of my code for example it gives errors saying tuples do not have a value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was covered in the [2.4 release notes](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/changes.html#id24): `ws.rows` and `ws.columns` now always return generators.

You probably just need `for cell in activeSheet[1]` for the cells in the first row.

Comment: Thanks, how do I distinguish between a row and a column using that method?